# DSolve version 9 won't solve simple o.d.e

Tags: differential-equations

`DSolve` returns the input expression unchanged. How can I fix this code?

```
 f[x : _] = Tanh[x]; f1[x : _] = D[f[x], x]; f2[x : _] = D[f1[x], x]                    
 DSolve[{(y'''[x] + 2*f[x]*y''[x] + 6*f2[x]*y[x] == 0), (y'[0] == 0)}, 
  y[x], x]  (* expect 2 c's *) hopefully to satisfy y'(+/-Inf)=+/- 1
```

All the solutions found fixups below give essentially the same solution of y'  LGP normalised by 67000 and LGQ by 105000. Something seriously overlooked by Mathematica

[image]

Comment: Even version 14 won't solve this "simple" ode, even if I expand all the f1 and f2., unless I've made a mistake. `DSolve[{y'''[x]+2 a Tanh[a x] y''[x]+6(-2 a^2 Sech[a x]^2 Tanh[a x])y[x]==0, y'[0]==0},y[x],x]` Can you show the "simple" solution by hand?

Comment: Thanks for trying later version. No immediate success by hand or with guesses.

Comment: Try to replace `a` with 1 or `TrigExpand` or `Apart` or add "simple" ic and use `NDSolve` to show it is well behaved with no zero denominators or infinite results, nothing I've tried makes this "simple" ode solve.

Comment: @Bill. Thanks alot for working on it. Yes vestigal a=1. No so far can't see how to solve numerically. meanwhile Maths exchange are giving me the gears. following is what I posted there,

Comment: Maple 2023.2.1 can solve it, but solution is very long to post. Here is partial screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxJ4i.png)  and has unresolved integrals. Mathematica 14.0 can solve it if you give `a` a numerical value, say `a=1` but answer is in terms of differential roots.

Comment: This problem comes from fluid mechanics. Trying to perturb Schlicting's jet F=tanht
 with a shear flow. t is actually a similarity varaible

g′′′+2Fg′′+6F′′g=0
with the boundary conditions: g′=0 at t=0; g′ tends to 1 as t tends to ∞ tends to − as t
 tends to −∞
 . Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake in entering the ode in Maple. It can actually solve it easily and solution is one line. But has unresolved integral. Will see if Mathemtica can do the integration, as Mathematica is little better than Maple in integration, but Maple is little better than Mathematica in dsolve.

Comment: @simon I' m not sure wether question is still of interest. If yes it seems, that your ode together with bc `y'[0]==0` only has a complex solution fullfilling `y[x]==-y[-x]`. Does this fit the physical problem

Answer (score 9):

Got the solution. Verified by Maple and Mathematica.

Maple can solve it and also verify it using its odetest() function.

I copied the solution to Mathematica. And also Mathematica verifies it.

This was all done with no IC used. Just general solution with 3 c's

```
f:=x->a*tanh(a*x);
ode:=diff(y(x),x$3)+2*f(x)*diff(y(x),x$2)+6*diff(f(x),x$2)*y(x)=0;
```

[image]

Now

```
sol:=dsolve(ode)
```

Gives

```
y(x) = c__1*sech(a*x)^2+c__2*Int(LegendreP(1/2*I*15^(1/2)-1/2,tanh(a*x))*cosh(a
*x)^2,x)*sech(a*x)^2+c__3*Int(LegendreQ(1/2*I*15^(1/2)-1/2,tanh(a*x))*cosh(a*x)
^2,x)*sech(a*x)^2
```

In Latex

$$
y \left(x \right) = 
c_{1} \mathrm{sech}\left(a x \right)^{2}+c_{2} \left(\int \mathit{LegendreP}\left(\frac{i \sqrt{15}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}, \tanh \left(a x \right)\right) \cosh \left(a x \right)^{2}d x \right) \mathrm{sech}\left(a x \right)^{2}+c_{3} \left(\int \mathit{LegendreQ}\left(\frac{i \sqrt{15}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}, \tanh \left(a x \right)\right) \cosh \left(a x \right)^{2}d x \right) \mathrm{sech}\left(a x \right)^{2}
$$

In Mathematica syntax the above is

```
f[x_] := a*Tanh[a*x];
ode = y'''[x] + 2*f[x]*y''[x] + 6*f''[x]*y[x] == 0;
DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No solution. Hopefully in Version 15 it will be able to solve it.

Here is the Maple solution converted to Mathematica syntax by hand:

```
f[x_] := a*Tanh[a*x];
ode = y'''[x] + 2*f[x]*y''[x] + 6*f''[x]*y[x] == 0;
integrand1 = LegendreP[Sqrt[15]*I/2 - 1/2, Tanh[a*x]]*Cosh[a*x]^2
integrand2 = LegendreQ[Sqrt[15]*I/2 - 1/2, Tanh[a*x]]*Cosh[a*x]^2
sol = y -> 
  Function[{x}, 
   Evaluate[
    C[1]*Sech[a*x]^2 + C[2]*Sech[a*x]^2*Integrate[integrand1, x] + 
     C[3]*Sech[a*x]^2*Integrate[integrand2, x]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verification

```
ode/.sol//FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Version 14 on windows 10.

**Update**

Using initial/boundary conditions given, Maple gives this solution

```
f:=x->a*tanh(a*x);
ode:=diff(y(x),x$3)+2*f(x)*diff(y(x),x$2)+6*diff(f(x),x$2)*y(x)=0;
ic:=D(y)(0)=0,D(y)(infinity)=1,D(y)(-infinity)=-1;
sol:=dsolve([ode,ic])
```

[image]

Which in Mathematica syntax is

```
Limit[ - Cosh[a*z]^2*Coth[a*z]*Sech[a*x]^2/(2*a),z->Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Are you sure these initial/boundary conditions are correct? Mathematica says the limit is $-\infty$ for positive $a$

---

**Update**

> Can you do the slider for integrand 1 for me so I know how to program
> it.

To evaluate numerically the above integrand 1 and 2, you can use slider and change the upper limit. Something like the following

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{integrand1, integrand2, a = 1, x},
  integrand1 = LegendreP[Sqrt[15]*I/2 - 1/2, Tanh[a*x]]*Cosh[a*x]^2;
  integrand2 = LegendreQ[Sqrt[15]*I/2 - 1/2, Tanh[a*x]]*Cosh[a*x]^2;
  Grid[{{"integrand 1 = ", NIntegrate[integrand1, {x, 0, upperLimit}]},
    {"integrand 2 = ", NIntegrate[integrand2, {x, 0, upperLimit}]}
    }]
  ],
 {{upperLimit, 3, "Upper limit?"}, 0, 20, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {upperLimit}
 ]
```

[image]

If the upper limit is too large you will get overflow messages from Mathematica.

You can change the limits as you want. Here is updated code

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{integrand1, integrand2, a = 1, x},
  integrand1 = LegendreP[Sqrt[15]*I/2 - 1/2, Tanh[a*x]]*Cosh[a*x]^2;
  integrand2 = LegendreQ[Sqrt[15]*I/2 - 1/2, Tanh[a*x]]*Cosh[a*x]^2;
  Grid[{{"integrand 1 = ", 
     Quiet@NIntegrate[integrand1, {x, lowerLimit, upperLimit}]},
    {"integrand 2 = ", 
     Quiet@NIntegrate[integrand2, {x, lowerLimit, upperLimit}]}
    }]
  ],
 {{upperLimit, 3, "Upper limit?"}, -10, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{lowerLimit, -10, "Lower limit?"}, -10, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {upperLimit, lowerLimit}
 ]
```

But numerical integration from minus infinity does not work, `NIntegrate` gives overflow errors.

---

**Update**

> to narrow it down further can you use ask Maple to solve with y'(0)=0

This is what Maple gives for just $y'(0)$ and the Mathematica code translation

```
a:=1;
f:=x->a*tanh(a*x);
ode:=diff(y(x),x$3)+2*f(x)*diff(y(x),x$2)+6*diff(f(x),x$2)*y(x)=0;
ic:=D(y)(0)=0;
sol:=dsolve([ode,ic]);
```

[image]

In plain text

```
y(x) = -(Int(LegendreP(1/2*I*15^(1/2)-1/2,tanh(_z1))*cosh(_z1)^2,_z1 = 0 .. x)*
GAMMA(3/4-1/4*I*15^(1/2))*GAMMA(3/4+1/4*I*15^(1/2))*LegendreQ(1/2*I*15^(1/2)-1/
2,0)*c__3-(c__3*Int(LegendreQ(1/2*I*15^(1/2)-1/2,tanh(_z1))*cosh(_z1)^2,_z1 = 0
.. x)+c__1)*Pi^(1/2))*sech(x)^2/Pi^(1/2)
```

manual translation using my own custom Maple to Mathematica translator gives

```
sol = -1/
   Sqrt[Pi] * (Integrate[
      LegendreP[1/2*I*15^(1/2) - 1/2, Tanh[z1]]*Cosh[z1]^2, {z1, 0, 
       x}]*Gamma[3/4 - 1/4*I*15^(1/2)]*Gamma[3/4 + 1/4*I*15^(1/2)]*
     LegendreQ[1/2*I*15^(1/2) - 1/2, 0]*
     C[3] - (C[3]*
        Integrate[
         LegendreQ[1/2*I*15^(1/2) - 1/2, Tanh[z1]]*Cosh[z1]^2, {z1, 
          0, x}] + C[1])*Pi^(1/2))*Sech[x]^2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150885/discussion-on-answer-by-nasser-dsolve-version-9-wont-solve-simple-o-d-e); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2.** Problem is fixed by moving the base point for integration. <s>Also multiplied `C[2]` by `I * C[2]` to get a real solution.</s> (There's a small imaginary part that is not a spurious round-off artifact.)

---

Here's a solution from `DSolve` giving it a nudge (the substitution $t = \tanh x$ converts the ODE to one with polynomial coefficients):

```
ivp = {ode, ic} = {
   (y'''[x] + 2*f[x]*y''[x] + 6*f2[x]*y[x] == 0),
   (y'[0] == 0)};

utDSolve = DSolveChangeVariables[
     Inactive[DSolve][ode, y[x], x],
     u, t, t == Tanh[x]];
utODE = First[utDSolve];
dsol = utDSolve // Activate // 
   ReplaceAll[{u[t] -> y[x], t -> Tanh[x]}] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ypAtZero = D[dsol, x] /. x -> 0 // FullSimplify
icsol = dsol /. 
     First@Solve[y'[0] == 0 /. ypAtZero, C[3]] /.
     {k_K, 1, b_} :> {k, 0, b} /. C[2] -> I*C[2] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ivp /. DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction[icsol] // FullSimplify
(* {{True, True}} *)
```

Visualization of two independent solutions $y=y(x)$ (axes $y$ vs. $x$):

```
 With[{yy = y /. DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction@icsol // First},
  solfunc[x_?NumericQ, c_] := 
   yy[x] /. Thread[{C[1], C[2]} -> c] /. 
    Inactive[Integrate] -> NIntegrate
  ];
 ReImPlot[Evaluate[solfunc[x, #] & /@ IdentityMatrix[2]], {x, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note on `solfunc`: It computes `y[x]` for a given numeric `x` and values of the constant parameters.  You can see the code it will call with `? solfunc` or in a simpler output, with

```
Block[{NumericQ = True &, NIntegrate},
 solfunc[x, {c1, c2}] // HoldForm[#] &
 ]
```

*Note on problem-solving:* The description in the OP and [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296415/dsolve-version-9-wont-solve-simple-o-d-e#comment733388_296415) suggest $t = \tanh x$ might be a natural variable to use; and if not, certainly $t = \exp x$ is worth trying. The first, $t = \tanh x$, leads to `utODE`, which is equivalent to the following:
$$\left(t^2-1\right)^2 u^{(3)}(t)+4 t \left(t^2-1\right)
   u''(t)+2 \left(t^2-1\right) u'(t)-12 t\, u(t)=0 \,.$$
So it's natural to see if there's a polynomial solution of low degree, which yields $u = 1-t^2 = 1-\tanh^2 x = \text{sech}^2 x$, which leads to the following...

**Bonus:** reduction-of-order solution $y = (\text{sech}^2 x)\,\int u\,dx$ (different `u` than above!!!):

```
redODE = ode /. y -> Function[x, Sech[x]^2 Derivative[-1][u][x]] // Simplify
DSolve[redODE, u, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One recovers the previous solution $y$ from by solving $u(0)=0$ for `C[2]` in terms of `C[1]` (this was `C[3]` in terms of `C[2]` in the solution for `icsol` above; and then integrating `u[t]` from $t=0$ to $t=\tanh x$. (`Integrate` cannot find it, so it the solution is represented as an unresolved integral.)

**Bonus 2:** Combine integrals; if used in `solfunc` (defined above the plot), then only one `NIntegrate` call per evaluation.

```
icsol2 = 
 icsol /. 
  a_  Inactive[Integrate][f_, {K[1], k1_, k2_}] + 
    b_  Inactive[Integrate][g_, {K[2], k1_, k2_}] :> 
   Inactive[Integrate][
    a  f + b  g /. K[2] -> K[1] // Simplify, {K[1], k1, k2}]
```

---

*Appendix – Response to comment*

To make the substitution, $\tanh x = t$, change  $\mathop{\text{sech}}^2 x = 1 - t^2$ and use ${d \over dx} = (1-t^2){d \over dt}$, which leads to the following replacements for $y$ and its derivatives:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 y(x) & u(t) \\
 y'(x) & -\left(\left(t^2-1\right) u'(t)\right) \\
 y''(x) & \left(t^2-1\right) \left(\left(t^2-1\right) u''(t)+2 t
   u'(t)\right) \\
 y^{(3)}(x) & -\left(\left(t^2-1\right) \left(\left(6
   t^2-2\right) u'(t)+\left(t^2-1\right) \left(\left(t^2-1\right)
   u^{(3)}(t)+6 t u''(t)\right)\right)\right) \\
\end{array}
$$
Or $y^{(3)}$ without simplification:
$$\left(1-t^2\right) \left(\left(1-t^2\right)
   \left(\left(1-t^2\right) u^{(3)}(t)-4 t u''(t)-2
   u'(t)\right)-2 t \left(\left(1-t^2\right) u''(t)-2 t
   u'(t)\right)\right)$$

If you don't like `DSolveChangeVariables`, which does all that for you, here are steps in a Mma code that give the left-hand side of the $u$ ODE above:

```
ode /.
        Thread[
               NestList[D[#, x] &, y[x], 3] -> 
                NestList[(1 - t^2) D[#, t] &, u[t], 3]] /.
       {Tanh[x] -> t, Sech[x]^2 -> 1 - t^2} /.
      Equal -> Subtract //
     FactorList //
    Collect[#, NestList[D[#, t] &, u[t], 3], Simplify] & //
   Last //
  First //
 TeXForm
```

`FactorList // Last // First` removes a common factor of $1-t^2$. There are other ways to divide it out. You can comment out the last few steps to see the result of an intermediate step, if you want to check them. I don't know what's so hard (well, doing a product rule multiple times gives many chances for a mistake, I suppose). Questions about that probably belong on Math.SE. As I said in a comment, this site is to show how to use Mathematica to do math (and other things), which I've tried to do, to complement Nasser's answer. I find some of the numerous comments confusing, since they describe things in terms not present in the original question or my answer, as if the OP is dealing with one problem and I'm dealing with a different one.

Comment: please I need an antisymmetric solution for y' which has a non-zero limit at infinity.

Comment: @simon Hi! (1) The axes are y vs. x (I added a note). (2) I don't understand the cosh comment. cosh is the reciprocal of sech and vice versa. Is cosh2 the same as $\cosh^2 x$? I don't have a $\cosh^2 x$, so I don't know what you're looking at. Maybe it's `dK[1]/(-1+K[1])^2` --> `Cosh[x]^2 dx` if `K[t] == Tanh[x]`? It becomes the same as Nasser's integral, no? (3) Mathematica did the math for me. I broke down some  steps and saved them in variables, so you can check your work vs. Mathematica's. I don't think the result is any different than Nasser's. I was showing how to get DSolve to work

Comment: @simon The second substitution is the standard reduction of order method for linear differential equations using a known solution. See [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/ReductionofOrder.aspx) or [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Elementary_Differential_Equations_with_Boundary_Value_Problems_(Trench)/05%3A_Linear_Second_Order_Equations/5.06%3A_Reduction_of_Order), etc. for standard treatments if you're unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Please  plot y'[x] for the 3 solutions instead of y[x] for the LG solutions and label your plots axes . You just seemed to have dumped the c1 soultion. That's was all the information I ever wanted in the first place like 36 hours ago. Please oblige.

Comment: Y'[0] looks zero for both LG's but you say not exactly. what I am dying to know is the limit of y'[x] as x goes to Plus or minus infinity

Comment: @nasser. All your 3 solutions give  identical g' overplot when LGP normalised by 67000 and LGQ by 105000. Something seriously overlooked by Mathematica

Comment: All your 3 solutions give  identical g' overplot when LGP normalised by 67000 and LGQ by 105000. Something seriously overlooked by Mathematica

Comment: Can't paste graph of all 3 overplotting each other even in my original question

Comment: @nasser More solutions still unknown, so question wasn't fully answered

Comment: I don't get your equation in Note on problem-solving: when I change variable to t=tanhx . Can you please post your working. or send it to SimonPFarthing@gmail.com

Comment: @Goofy Clever idea to substitude `t->a Tanh[a x]` . Finally the ode is solved analytically if Mathematica is able to solve integral `Inactive[Integrate][
 LegendreP[1/2 I (I + Sqrt[15]), K[1]/a]/(a^2 - K[1]^2)^2, {K[1], 1, 
  t}]`