# Mathematica gives 2 integral solutions to a 3rd degree ode which compute identical to simple solution, so 2 solutions still unknown

Tags: differential-equations

Re [DSolve version 9 won't solve simple o.d.e](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296415/dsolve-version-9-wont-solve-simple-o-d-e)  I computed the integral in from large x as  part of the derivative of the solution and when rescaled they coincided with the derivative of the simple.

1. 2 solutions are still missing
2. There is an analytic answer to 2 Legendre integrals Mathematica doesn't know

   pj = Plot[2*Sinh[x]/Cosh[x]^3, {x, -6.6, 6.6}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Green}]

   pp = Plot[(LegendreP[-(1/2) + (I Sqrt[15])/2, Tanh[t]] -
   2*Sech[t]^2*Tanh[t]*NIntegrate[Cosh[x]^
   2 LegendreP[-(1/2) + (I Sqrt[15])/2, Tanh[x]], {x, 6.6, t}])/
   67000, {t, 6.59999, -6.6}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
   pq = Plot[(Im[LegendreQ[-(1/2) + (I Sqrt[15])/2, Tanh[t]]] -
   2*Sech[t]^2*Tanh[t]*NIntegrate[Cosh[x]^
   2 Im[LegendreQ[-(1/2) + (I Sqrt[15])/2, Tanh[x]]], {x, 6.6,
   t}])/-105000, {t, 6.59999, -6.6}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]
   Show[pj, pp, pq]

[image]